# Sanitize data from Rails controller variable passing into React component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I've got a Profile model that users can create that includes some sensitive data like SIN number, etc. I'm doing server-side rendering of react components in the views. So I'm doing the typical `@profiles = Profile.all` and passing down the object as props into the react component. But I don't want users to be able to access things like SIN, BirthDate, email on the front-end on a public page.

How could I sanitize this information so that only the information I specify is passed with the `@profiles` object?

Comment: If you're not working with your profiles collection after the query (meaning you're just returning the `@profiles` collection for your React components), then you can just use `select` as the other comment suggests. If you need to do anything with the profile columns that you _don't_ want to return, then you could use a [serializer](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_model_serializers/0.8.2/ActiveModel/Serializer) or use [as_json](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

Comment: @maxpleaner this works (although it would be more efficient of there were the opposite sort of method, so I could just exclude a few rows). If you want to re-write as the answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.